# If you can't change a variable's value in Haskell, how do you create data structures?

Tags: variables, data-structures, haskell, constants

As per the title.

I have the following code which creates a binary search tree, but if I want it created and changed dynamically with user input, how would I do that if I can't change the value of a variable in haskell?!?

```
find :: (Ord a) => Node a -> a -> Bool
find (Node val left right) s
    | s == val      = True
    | s < val       = find left s
    | s > val       = find right s

find Empty s = False

data Node a = Node a (Node a) (Node a)
              | Empty

myTree = Node "m"   (Node "a" Empty Empty)
                    (Node "z" Empty Empty)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12):

The idea behind purely functional data structures is to compute new values instead of changing them and to pass them (recursively) in parameters instead of storing them globally.

So given a function

```
insert :: Ord a => Node a -> a -> Node a
```

your programm could look like this

```
-- Let the user enter k values that are stored in a tree structure
addTreeItems :: Int -> Node Int -> IO (Node Int)
addTreeItems 0 tree = return tree
addTreeItems k tree = do
    putStr "Enter new item: "
    item <- readLn
    addTreeItems (k - 1) (insert tree item) -- Recursively pass the tree

main = do
    tree <- addTreeItems 10 Empty
    -- ...
```

Using monadic helper functions, this could be simplified to things like

```
(foldl insert Empty) `liftM` (sequence $ replicate k (putStr "Enter new item: " >> readLn))
```

If you want to update values at a certain position, you'll need more advanced datastructures like a [zipper](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Zippers), that are nevertheless still purely functional!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I don't mean to be dense but with the example given I still seem to have the same problem. You get to 'insert tree item', tree is a node with left and right nodes attached which may be 'Empty' or not. The first time addTreeItems is called it is called again with a tree returned by 'insert tree item' which would just have a single node with presumably two empty branches. The second recursion has this root node passed into insert along with a new item, but how is that item added to the node if the node's branches cannot be changed (from empty in this case)?

Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind I was being dense, forgot that I need to create an entirely new tree, I'm close to my own solution I think now.

Answer (score 6):

Dario gave a good direct answer.  If you want more in-depth information, there's [*Purely Functional Data Structures*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504) by Chris Okasaki, an entire book on the subject.  I bought it myself, but sadly, I don't have the time to experiment with the ideas.

Comment: The book is based on his Ph.D. thesis, so if you can't afford it, you can peruse the [thesis](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf).

Comment: @Don Wakefield Thank you for that.  Honestly any day where you find a reference or knowledge you didn't have yesterday is a good day.  Thank you so much for referencing that thesis!

Answer (score 2):

You allocate a new tree node and the old one sticks around.  This technique requires a really good allocator, but it enables all sorts of nifty devices because other parts of the program still have access to old nodes.  This is a godsend for certain kinds of speculative algorithms or other tricks involving so-called "persistent data structures".

Eventually you allocate a new root for your tree and what then?  As Dario says, you pass it as a parameter to a function (instead of storing it in a global variable).

So

- Mutation of a field in a struct allocated on the heap becomes allocation of a new struct on the heap.
- Mutation of a global variable becomes passing a parameter to a function

Sometimes it also makes sense to take what would have been a collection of global variables in C and put them all in an object allocated on heap.

---

P.S. If you really want to, you *can* have mutable global variables in Haskell.  It is, after all, the world's finest imperative programming language (according to Wadler or Peyton Jones, I forget whom).  But if you are asking this question, you really don't want to.  Yet.