# Is a Java lambdas equivalent to a JavaScript closures?

Tags: javascript, java, lambda, functional-programming, closures

I started learning about functional programming and I'm a bit confusing about it.

**My question is:** is Java lambdas equivalent to JavaScript closures? If not, what is the difference between them?

Comment: "The term closure is often mistakenly used to mean anonymous function." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)#Anonymous_functions - good reading material

Comment: I don't know Java lambdas but I guess they are "similar" to arrow functions in Javascript: `const flip f => y => x => f(x) (y)`. `flip(someF)` returns a lambda that closes over `f` and expects another argument `y` etc. As you can see you need closures for currying in Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are "slightly different" and also "roughly equivalent".

tldr; a Java lambda that access an outer-scoped variable<sup>1</sup> is *also* a closure; and a JavaScript "closure" that does not access an outer-scope variable is *not* strictly a closure (and can be more precisely called an anonymous function<sup>2</sup>).

---

In JavaScript, a closure generally implies "being able to re-assign variables in the outer scope" - however, having access to or "closing over / binding" a variable is *sufficient* for an anonymous function to be a closure<sup>3</sup>.

Java lambda's requires that all variables from the outer scope accessed in a lambda are *effectively final* which means they cannot be re-assigned.

> <sup>1</sup>The rule is that a [Java] lambda expression can only access local variables from an enclosing scope that are effectively final. An effectively final variable is never modified—it either is or could be declared as final - http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2303960

However, since a Java lambda *can* capture a read-only variable binding to mutable objects, it is possible for a Java lambda to indirectly modify state in the outer context and can thus emulate the ability to "re-assign" values.

> <sup>2</sup>In computer science, a closure is a function that has an environment of its own. Inside this environment, *there is at least one bound variable [and] anonymous functions are sometimes wrongly called closures*. This is probably because most languages [eg. JavaScript] that have anonymous functions also have closures and it's common for programmers to learn about both at the same time. - https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)

Java also has different semantics on `this` inside a lambda vs a JS anon-function / closure; also see JavaScript ["arrow functions"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which have different rules than traditional anonymous functions on how `this` behaves.

---

<sup>3</sup> Trivial argument:

- [Haskell has closures](https://wiki.haskell.org/Closure).
- [Haskell does not allow variables to be re-assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804679/if-you-cant-change-a-variables-value-in-haskell-how-do-you-create-data-struct).
- Therefore, re-assignment (or mutability) is not a requirement of closures.

Comment: *Java lambda that access an outer-scoped variable1 is also a closure;* But, that is not what the question was at all. You are creating a relationship between lambdas and closures and passing that off as them being "roughly equivalent" when what you are really saying is that if you use a lambda to create a closure, then, yes, they are close to the same thing. But, lambdas, in and of themselves, are not at all related to closures.

Comment: Also, when you say *In JavaScript, a closure generally implies "being able to re-assign variables in the outer scope" - however, having access to a variable is sufficient for an anonymous function to be a closure3.*, you imply that closures and anonymous functions have some direct relationship, when, in fact, closures can be created and used completely without anonymous functions.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The above comments have been noted; however, I feel this answer sufficiently covers key differences between JavaScript "closures" (or anonymous functions that do not establish such a binding) and Java lambdas (and their equivalent ability to establish a binding) fairly clearly. I've outlined the points above in context of the question and specific languages.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not equivalent. One has to do with syntax and the other with memory.

Lambdas are a short-hand syntax for declaring anonymous code structures.

Closures are when a nested function (named or not) holds a reference to a variable from a function in an outer scope. That, in and of itself isn't really an issue. But, when the nested function persists longer than the outer scoped variable, the variable won't be garbage collected when the outer scope terminates. That's when closures become either very powerful or very annoying. It all depends on if you are intentionally using them or not. Closures can allow for shared access to private data.

Comment: P.S. it is often misleading to consider a variable as something that is "garbage collected". P.P.S. the outer scope does not need to "terminate" before a variable might relinquish any *strong reference* it establishes. Since, it's like minutia day.

Comment: "_Closures can allow for shared access to private data_" um, functional programming?